# jQuery fadein image on link hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple menu, where hovering over different elements fades in a different image over the menu. My best guest was to create a jQuery, but it does not seem to work.
Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pau").mouseover(function(){
        $("#paup").show.fadeIn(600);
    $("#pau").mouseout(function(){
        $("#paup").fadeOut(600);
    });
});
```

#pau div only defines the text part, over which an image should be faded in. And here is the div for the image I would like to get shown, when I hover over #pau:

```
#paup{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-top:90px;
    width:100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!--This is a script to change opacity of img.-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js">     </script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#pau").mouseover(function(){
                $("#paup").fadeIn(600);
    $("#pau").mouseout(function(){
                        $("#paup").fadeOut(600);
                    });
                         });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='box'>
<div id="paup"><img src="./images/paulinemma.jpg"/></div>
<div class='logo'>#najforever</div>
<div class='people'>
    <table style="width:100%" height="70px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="pau">
                <ul>
                    <li>redpoppy stories</li>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Vimeo</a></li>
                        </ul>   
                </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
       .....
```

Could you please advise why my script is not working? Thanks

Comment: Please add your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have some syntax error:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#pau").mouseover(function(){
    $("#paup").fadeIn(600);
});

$("#pau").mouseout(function(){
    $("#paup").fadeOut(600);
});

});
```

Working Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hro1e6kn/

Comment: thanks @insane-skull ! this is actually working. However, I now realized the picture fades in and out everytime I hover over the li menu items. could you please suggest a way that the picture would stay shown during li hover, and only fade out when I move the mouse outside the ul and li? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

change

`$("#paup").show.fadeIn(600);`

to

`$("#paup").fadeIn(600);`

**Update : Please change the code in `document.ready` with**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#pau").mouseover(function(){
        $("#paup").fadeIn(600);
    });

    $("#pau").mouseout(function(){
        $("#paup").fadeOut(600);
    });

});
```

you did not complete the callabck function in fadeIn